# Do I need to Install .Net 1.1 Framework on server to host Web app in Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Do I need to Install .Net 1.1 Framework on server to host Web app in Visual Studio 2003?
I have all .net dlls in GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the framework needs to be installed. You also may need (if installed post IIS) to register them with IIS... For that go to the framework directory in c:\winnt... and run "aspnet_regiis -i", which will add the hooks to IIS.

No, you can not install ASp.NET 2003 - there is no 2003 ;) This would be... hm... ASP.NET 1.1 or 1.0, which is not supported on modern servers properly.

Rather upgrade to 2008 / .NET 3.5sp1 upward.

Comment: Actually I tried running 1.1 ASP.Net web app on server on which 1.0/1.1 framework is not installed but have 2.0 Framework installed.I checked GAC 1.0/1.1 dlls are present.In IIS properties ASP.NET tabs "ASP.NET version" shows me only 2.0 not 1.0/1.1.
My application is running.So this thing is confusing me.Without framework my web app is working.Please provide some clarity regarding this.Does GAC Dlls are sufficient to run 1.0/1.1 .net application?

Comment: No idea. You dont do somethng supported and I stopped even caring about .NET 1.1 the moment 2.0 came out with generics.

Comment: ASP.NET 2.0 is backward compatible and in most cases it should be possible to run ASP.NET 1.1 applications on a server with only ASP.NET 2.0 installed, so if it works for you - great, but you should try and upgrade to the latest framework unless there is a good reason not to.